# How to get the unique string values in a column with numbers and characters in python

Tags: python, string, dataframe, character, unique

I want to print the unique values taken in this column and not the numerical ones.
I only want to output the values taken before the special characters (when there is one) and I don't want the second part of the string.
For example for the row "lala :59 lzenvke" I don't want to take into account "lzenvke" but only "lala"

```
import pandas as pd



data1 = {
    'column_with_names': ['lala :56 javcejhv', 'lala56 : javcejhv' 'li :lo 7TUF', 'lo','lala :59 lzenvke','la','lala','lalalo'],

}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

print(df1)
```

the expected output would be:

[image]

Comment: Your input data frame has 7 rows but your output only has 4.

Comment: Yes I want to output unique data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way about it

Assumption: rows that don't have : are also included in the result set

```
import numpy as np

# split the values on colon (:), limited to 1 split, and form list (with expand)
# take the first element
# find unique using np.unique
# finally create a DF


pd.DataFrame(np.unique(df['column_with_names'].str.split(r'[\s|:]', 1, expand=True)[0]))
```

```
    0
0   la
1   lala
2   lala
3   lalalo
4   li
5   lo
```

if you only need to consider the rows with the colon in it

```
# same as above, except filter out the rows with colon beforehand
(pd.DataFrame(
    np.unique(df.loc[df['column_with_names'].str.contains(':')]['column_with_names']
              .str.split('[\s|:]', 1, expand=True)[0])))
```

```
    0
0   lala
1   li
```

Comment: I encountered a little issue as I had in my column (not in the example) a value like "lala 56: kznlkzan" and it returned "lala 56" but I don't want the numerical data, only "lala". How would it be possible to return only "lala"? Thank you so much!

Comment: updated the solution to split on space or colon. is that what you're after?

Comment: yes! but I get the message   pd.DataFrame(np.unique(df_cities["Status"].str.split([\s|:], 1, expand=True)[0]))
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

workd perfectly with "'[\s|:]' many thanks!!

Comment: oops!, forgot the quotes. check it now. solution updated